# Javascript to pause execution and wait for a called function to return value

Tags: javascript

I have a function in javascript that runs another function and it should wait for the called function to complete its execution and return control back to the calling function. However, this doesn't happen and after called function starts executing, the calling function doesn't wait and falls right through.

```
function ButtonClick() {

    AskQuestion(param1, param2, function (success) {

        if (success == true) {
           //do some staff here
        }

    }

}

function AskQuestion(param1, param2) {

   //here I present a dialog box and ask users to fill it out, then I 
   //validate their entry. If it's validated then I do: `return true` and 
   //if it's not: `return false`

}
```

Right after I call AskQuestion function, it doesn't wait and `success` will always be `FALSE`
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I suggest you look what a `callback` is in Javascript. It answers exactly your question.

Comment: Is there any asynchronous code involved inside "AskQuestion" function ?

Comment: @Val Berthe...I thought I was using callback actually.

Comment: @SiddharthaChowdhury I'm not exactly sure. I'm using a 3rd party JS plugin in that function.

Comment: I mean, unless you know if there is any piece of code that is async, or may be what its doing, any solution would be shooting in the dark. For the purpose of debugging add a setTimeout( () => {  if (success == true) ...  },xxx) around the checking, see if its returning your desired value after a time.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a callback to AskQuestion, the function has to accept a callback, and actually call that back if the asynchronous tasks are done:

```
function ButtonClick() {

    AskQuestion(param1, param2, function (success) { // This anonymous function will be called at the end of the AskQuestion execution

        if (success == true) {
            //do some staff here
        }

    });

}

function AskQuestion(param1, param2, callback) {

   //here I present a dialog box and ask users to fill it out, then I 
   //validate their entry. If it's validated then I do: `return true` and 
   //if it's not: `return false`

  callback(success); // assuming success is a variable set to true if no problem happened 

}
```

Comment: Don't know who downvoted it. I upvoted it :-) Anyway I tried your approach and still falls right through for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As Gregory pointed out you should probably call the callback somewhere in your code passing the result of the result you want and then processing it in the callback.

But it depends on what you're using to present a dialog box.
For example window.prompt() stops the execution of the JavaScript until the user gives a feedback.

```js
function giveMeYouName() {
 var name = prompt('Could you please give me your name?');
 console.log('Your name is: ' + name);
}

giveMeYouName();
```

Name is printed only after you submit the prompt.

Comment: I'm using 3rd party js plugin to display this dialog. I don't believe it uses PROMPT

Comment: What's function signature? Because maybe if it doesn't use a callback it returns a promise.

Comment: Hi @Tom....the function from the 3rd party plugin accepts bunch of parameters and none of it is a callback. So if this is the case, there's nothing I can do?

Comment: Hi @Tony, try to check if the function returns a _Promise_ as return value.

Comment: Hi @Tom, I don't see it returning or using Promise.